# React App: D3 Chart not showing up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have made a simple React app with a reusable Bar Chart. However, nothing is getting displayed in the DOM. Here is my component DataSeries:

```
render: function() {
var props = this.props;

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(this.props.data)])
  .range([0, this.props.height]);

var xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(d3.range(this.props.data.length))
  .rangeRoundBands([0, this.props.width], 0.05);

var bars = this.props.data.map(function(point, i) {
  return (
    <Bar height={yScale(point)} width={xScale.rangeBand()} offset={xScale(i)} availableHeight={props.height} color={props.color} key={i} />
  )
});

return (
  <g>{bars}</g>
);}
```

The console is throwing the following error:
`DataSeries.js:41 Uncaught TypeError: d3.scaleOrdinal(...).domain(...).rangeRoundBands is not a function
    at Constructor.render (webpack:///./src/DataSeries.js?:41:77)
    at eval (webpack:///./~/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:793:21)
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (webpack:///./~/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:74:12)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (webpack:///./~/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:792:27)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (webpack:///./~/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:819:34)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (webpack:///./~/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:361:30)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (webpack:///./~/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:257:21)
    at Object.mountComponent (webpack:///./~/react/lib/ReactReconciler.js?:47:35)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (webpack:///./~/react/lib/ReactMultiChild.js?:240:44)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (webpack:///./~/react/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js?:699:32)`

Why is d3.scaleOrdinal().domain.rangeRoundBands() not a function? Since it is processing the code till that line, I assume d3.scaleLinear is fine. What is the issue?

Comment: I made a change to the scaleOrdinal function as: `d3.scaleOrdinal().domain().range()`. The console then threw an error that `xScale.rangeBand() is not a function`. I changed that too, to `xScale.range()`, but now it is not sending the correct argument to another component which is using this DataSeries component. So I guess this is a problem in executing the rangeRoundBand() and rangeBand() functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. `d3.scaleOrdinal().domain().rangeRoundBand()` and `rangeBand()` are d3v3 functions whereas I am using d3v4. The corresponding functions in v4 are:
`d3.scaleBand().domain().rangeRound().padding(`) and
`bandwith()`